Fingerprint Verification Problem - Thinkpad T480
fprintd was not working, so I installed "open-fprintd", which successfully enrolles the new fingerprints, but not verifying any. Actually I tried command "fprint-enroll" with and without "sudo" ans ended up two different types of fingerprints, sudo ones gets verified successfully in terminal. But when I'm trying to login into the system, fingerprint doesn't work. What sould I do next?
